# react native - how to put value from TextInput field into the Text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to react native and i'm trying see if i can enter a string in the input field and then with the press of a button let it appear in the Text field beneath it.

I tried `alert(this.state.PlaatsNaam)` at the end of the `handleSearchButtonPress` function and after the second button press it shows the alert with the given input from before.

Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#405162',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  roundedButton: {
    borderRadius: 90,
  },
});

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      PlaatsNaam: '',
      PlaatsInput: '',
    };
  }

  handleSearchButtonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      PlaatsNaam: this.state.PlaatsInput
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', marginLeft: 60, marginRight: 60, marginTop: 50 }}>
          <TextInput value={this.state.PlaatsInput} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({PlaatsInput: text})} autoCompleteType={"off"} style={{ flex: 4, textDecorationLine: 'none', color: '#ECF0F1', borderColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginBottom: 10 }} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleSearchButtonPress} style={{ borderTopEndRadius: 5, borderBottomRightRadius: 5, backgroundColor: '#16A085', height: 30, width: 40, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Icon color='#ECF0F1' size={20} name="search" style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 4 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>


        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 45, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}>{this.props.PlaatsInput}</Text>
        </View>


        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 25, borderTopRightRadius: 25, backgroundColor: "#2C3E50", width: 280, height: 180, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 90, color: '#ECF0F1' }} > {this.props.Temp} </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#ECF0F1' }} > {this.props.MinMaxTemp} </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#ECF0F1' }} > {this.props.datum} </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ borderBottomLeftRadius: 25, borderBottomRightRadius: 25, backgroundColor: "#ECF0F1", width: 280, height: 240, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 25 }} >{this.props.WindInfo}</Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center' }} >{this.props.WeatherDetails}</Text>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 25 }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginRight: 50 }} >{this.props.SunriseTime}</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 50 }} >{this.props.SunsetTime}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>


        <View style={{ height: 70, width: 400, justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#ECF0F1', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: "#2C3E50", width: 98 }}><Icon color='#ECF0F1' size={60} name="home" style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 7 }} /></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: "#2C3E50", width: 98 }}><Icon color='#ECF0F1' size={48} name="calendar-o" style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10 }} /></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: "#2C3E50", width: 98 }}><Icon color='#ECF0F1' size={48} name="calendar" style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10 }} /></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: "#2C3E50", width: 98 }}><Icon color='#ECF0F1' size={50} name="cog" style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10 }} /></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's updating your state properly you should just be able to write

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: 90, color: '#ECF0F1' }}>{this.state.PlaatsNaam}</Text>
```

I didn't run the code, but the logic is there

1. Update temp state as text input changes
2. Copy temp state to field that will be displayed on button click
3. Now you just need to display it

Also, `setState` does not guarantee that the state will change immediately.  That might be what's tripping you up with the alert.

Comment: This did it for me, and unlike the alert, the recieved input comes after the first button press. Thank you!